# Создание приложения под Android с использованием удаленной базы данных

Tags: android, база-данных, клиент-сервер

Необходимо разработать приложение со списком преподавателей и со списком студентов,но так что бы все находилось на удаленной базе данных и можно было просто с помощью интернета зайти и посмотреть список например.
Вопрос:Есть ли сервис уже с готовой удаленной базой,где нужно просто её настроить под себя,не делая back-end код и не создавать её с нуля,просто настроить пару табличек и уже брать или помещать туда значения??

Comment: Попробуйте посмотреть Firebase [ссылка](https://firebase.google.com/)

Comment: Я уже присматривался к ней, правда как я понял там нельзя создать несколько таблиц, а только одну

Comment: @AkiStar там вприципе нет таблиц, информация хранится в Firebase в файле JSON. Вы можете сделать два узла (преподаватели и студенты) и добавить в них элементы в одном файле.
https://firebase-info.com/2017/01/05/%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B-firebase-1-1-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-firebase-realtime-database-%D0%B8-sql/

Comment: [firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/) может быть более подходящей. в бесплатные квоты поместиться проблем быть не должно.

Comment: https://mlab.com/ настоящая монга на 0.5гига бесплатно навсегда.